# Why does the javascript interpreter get -8 as the result for the statement parseInt(1/8-9,23)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
parseInt(1/8-9,23);
> -8
```

Any help with how this works would be good.

Comment: What would you _expect_ to get as a result of that?

Comment: Divide 1 by 8. Subtract 9 from the result. Parse the result as a number in base 23. Profit.

Comment: In all seriousness, I think it ignores the radix argument if it's not 10 or a power of 2 so you're looking at (1 / 8 - 9) which is -8.875 truncated to an integer (-8).

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt radix can be _An integer between 2 and 36_

Comment: I think the main point is that 8 < 23, so -8 in base 23 is -8!

Comment: According to  operator  precedence '/' has higher precedence than '-' so 1/8 will execute and substract from -9 will be equal to -8.875 and parse int of it -8. -8 base of 23 is -8 . so answer is -8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the expected answer.  From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt:

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates
>   numbers to integer values

So, `-8.875` is parsed, the `.` is not valid as an integer so it is truncated to `-8`.  Since `8 < 23`, `-8` in base `23` is `-8`